# PhpDesigner8 shorcut exist for...?

Tags: phpdesigner

PhpDesigner8 shorcut exist? 
for toogle visit between two page while more than 2 pages opened in this editor

like page1. pag2.php page3.php page4.php 
and current page is page3.php and want to jump on page4.php and vice versa